# Making a circular/orbit diagram?

Tags: diagrams, circles

How can I make something like this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you  tried so far?

Comment: This is an easy job for the graphical package called [PGF/Ti*k*Z](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A short code with `pst-euclid`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl, multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.2,-2.2)(2.2,2.2)
\SpecialCoor
\pnode(0,0){O}
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointNameSep=0pt]%
 (0,2){A}(2,0){B}(0,-2){C}(-2,0){D}
 \pnodes{A}(2;85)(2;5)(2;-5)(2;-86)(2;-95)(2;-175)(2;175)(2;93)
\psset{nodesepA=1em, arrows=->, arrowinset=0}
\multido{\ie=0+2,\io=1+2}{4}{\pstArcnOAB[linewidth=2.5pt]{O}{A\ie}{A\io}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### EDIT: the `bending` library

When drawing large lines with arrows, the bending is not respected, unless you use the `bending` library (doesn't need anything else than declaring it in the preamble). Now this looks like a real circle.

[image: Four letters in circle]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \angle/\letter in {90/A,0/B,-90/C,180/D}
            \node (\letter) at (\angle:2) {\textbf{\sffamily \huge \letter}};
%       \foreach \a/\b in {A/B,B/C,C/D,D/A}     
%           \draw[line width=5pt,-latex] (\a) to[bend left,looseness=1] (\b);
        \def\shft{15}
        \foreach \angle in {0,-90,-180,-270}
            {
            \draw[line width=5pt] (-\shft+\angle:2) arc(-\shft+\angle:-70+\shft+\angle:2);  
            \draw[line width=5pt,-latex] (-70+\shft+\angle:2) arc(-70+\shft+\angle:-90+\shft+\angle:2);
            }    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I will use the option latex instead of stealth for the tips. +1

Comment: You're right. I'm so used to use stealth by default, I didn't even think of changing them ;)

Comment: I edited my answer to add the use of the `bending` library, which allows the bending to really follow the arcs, even with large line width.

Comment: Hi, have you seen that now is it better? :-) The tips are excellent.

Answer (score 7):

This is your diagram done with `xy` package (especially to built the commutative diagrams).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{
& A\ar@/^.9pc/[dr] &  \\
D \ar@/^.9pc/[ur]& & B\ar@/^.9pc/[dl]\\
& C\ar@/^.9pc/[ul] & }\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Admittedly a lot more colorful than the image in the question but probably nevertheless useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{A, B, C, D}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great!  Thank you!